# Invalid Date whilst using Moment() and Linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, charts

I am having a problem where I have a 12 month period but beginning from zero index and its causing me to have an invalid date. Below is a picture of both my date array and chart js. Basically, because the months are zero indexed, they are out by one

[image]

[image]

and the below is the Linq query I am using, if anyone can help me fix this that would be great

```
 var solicitor = _db.Records
               .Where(j => j.Requestor == "Solicitor" && EF.Functions.DateDiffMonth(j.Request_Date, DateTime.Now) == 0 && EF.Functions.DateDiffMonth(j.Request_Date, DateTime.Now) <= 12)
               .GroupBy(g => new { g.Request_Date.Value.Year, g.Request_Date.Value.Month }).OrderBy(d => d.Key.Year).ThenBy(d => d.Key.Month)
               .Select(group => new
                   {
                   Dates = group.Key,
                   Count = group.Count()
                   });

            var solicitorCount = solicitor.Select(n => n.Count).ToArray();
            var date = solicitor.Select(n => n.Dates).ToArray();
```

and the code inside my chart js to format as moment

```
let newArr = []
for (let i = 0; i < simpleData[0].date.length; i++) {
    var calDate = moment(simpleData[0].date[i]).format('MMM YYYY');
    console.log(calDate)
    newArr.push(calDate)



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like this:

```
let newArr = []
for (let i = 0; i < simpleData[0].date.length; i++) {
    data[i].month -= 1;
    var calDate = moment(simpleData[0].date[i]).format('MMM YYYY');
    console.log(calDate)
    newArr.push(calDate)
}
```

newArr result:
[image]